# Create a dashboard to track reporting upload delays

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, document-library

I have a SharePoint library in which users are supposed to upload several reports every month after a certain date. The files uploaded have mandatory properties to determine the report name / month / year.

For each report there is a due date (e.g. the 5th of the month). The list of reports is saved in a SharePoint list and contains: report name, due date (number of days from the 1st of the month).

I would like to have a table dashboard that can tell me for the list of reports I am supposed to receive for a specific month, which one are on time, delayed, missing. Dashboard should look like this

```
Name     | Due date | Jan-13  | ... | Dec-13
-------------------------------------------------
Report 1 |  +5      | On time | ... | On time
Report 2 |  +15     | Missing | ... | Not due yet
...      |  +2      | On time | ... | Delayed
Report N |  +5      | Delayed | ... | On time
```

Is this feasible with SharePoint? Which way would you do so? I just need to be guided in the right direction as I don't know all capabilities around SharePoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by creating an application page with a grid or table and fill it in the page’s code-behind. This way you have full control to customize the page as you want.

If you don’t want to write custom code you can try getting as close as possible to your requirements by adding calculated columns and creating views with filters and grouping. You do this using UI only but you will probably have to compromise with your requirements.

Comment: So that would be like C# code for the option 1?
Isn't there a way to have an Excel/Access file that could pull the data out of the library for analysis otherwise?

Comment: Yes, option 1 involves coding in C#. Another option is to Export to Excel and work with the Sheet. To get the latest versions from the list you have to refresh the Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show missing files then you will need a way of selecting what should be there.  I have done this in the past with a term set and a workflow - so grab all terms in the term set so I know what should be in the library and then grab all the items in the library for the current period.  You can then loop through comparing them to produce your output.  In my case I was using Nintex and sent the dashboard as an email but hopefully this gives you some ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Sounds exactly like what I want to do. Do you think with the latest SharePoint (2013) we could do this without Nintex?

Comment: Well you could certainly have your required items in a list rather than a term set which would make that bit easier.  Not sure about looping through an array - but I am sure you could come up with another approach to work around it.